# pandas to_numeric errors='coerce' doesn't coerce when number outside int64

Tags: python, pandas, casting

I am designing a workflow which cleans up very messy data submitted by third parties,
I'm running into an issue with numeric conversion. Specifically, I'm using 
the [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) to take data which is received and stored as text, and
test whether or not it contains valid numbers.  (Yes, I know it would be easier
to sanitize user input earlier, but that is unfortunately not a possibility
in this situation.)

The issue I'm running into is that pandas.to_numeric seems to fail silently
when it encounters an integer outside of the +/- 2^64 size range. **Is this
expected behavior?**

If it is expected behavior, is there a way to work around it programmatically?
I've found that it correctly coerces numeric values outside of the 2^64 
restriction, but not integers.

---

Here's a minimal example of just the problematic component:

```
import pandas
# when converting text representations of numbers to 
# numbers, the conversion fails if the number is very 
# large (~2^64)
integer_version_success = pandas.to_numeric(
    pandas.Series(
        name = 'values',
        index = range(2),
        # works even when adding a bit beyond 2^64
        data = ['9223372036854775807','.50001']), 
    errors='coerce')

print(integer_version_success)
# 0    9.223372e+18
# 1    5.000100e-01
# Name: values, dtype: float64

integer_version_failure = pandas.to_numeric(
    pandas.Series(
        name = 'values',
        index = range(2),
        # one digit longer, outside range
        data = ['92233720368547758071','.50001']), 
    errors='coerce')

print(integer_version_failure)
# 0    92233720368547758071
# 1                  .50001
# Name: values, dtype: object
#  | bad, leads to unexpected results

# when converting text representations of numbers to numbers, 
# the conversion succeeds if the number is already represented 
# as a number (non-int), regardless of if it's larger than 2^64
numeric_version_success = pandas.to_numeric(
    pandas.Series(
        name = 'values',
        index = range(2),
        # one digit longer, outside range  
        data = ['92233720368547758071.0','.50001']), 
    errors='coerce')

print(numeric_version_success)
# 0    9.223372e+19
# 1    5.000100e-01
# Name: values, dtype: float64 
#   | putting a decimal in the string maxes coercion succeed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is due to an issue in 0.20.3, which is resolved when running on 0.22.0.**

The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) does not say `coerce` will raise an exception (it will set those to NaN that you can later remove if wanted), you could change it to `raise` or don't set it as `raise` is the default.

With pandas 0.22.0:

```
0    9.223372e+18
1    5.000100e-01
Name: values, dtype: float64
0        NaN
1    0.50001
Name: values, dtype: float64
0    9.223372e+19
1    5.000100e-01
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, and you're right that `raise` does return an explicit ValueError (in this case, `ValueError: Integer out of range. at position 0`).  My point is that `coerce` is supposed to return NaN when it fails to coerce, and it doesn't, instead it just gives up and returns the original object.

Comment: I ran your code on pandas 0.22.0 (I just installed it) and it does return the NaN, maybe the version you were running on had a bug

Comment: Thanks! I checked the machine I produced the original example on, and it was running v. 0.20.3. This works.